# How would I convert this code to a functional style?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would you recommend that i add a function to shorten this code and make it more effective?

this needs to include atleast one function please help

```
import random


character1 = []
character2 = []
roll12 = int(random.randrange(1, 12, 1))
roll4 = int (random.randrange(1, 4, 1))
x = int(roll12 / roll4)
character1strength = x

roll12 = int(random.randrange(1, 12, 1))
roll4 = int (random.randrange(1, 4, 1))
x = int(roll12 / roll4)
character1skill = x

roll12 = int(random.randrange(1, 12, 1))
roll4 = int (random.randrange(1, 4, 1))
x = int(roll12 / roll4)
character2strength = x

roll12 = int(random.randrange(1, 12, 1))
roll4 = int (random.randrange(1, 4, 1))
x = int(roll12 / roll4)
character2skill = x

character1.append("strength")
character1.append(character1strength)
character1.append('skill')
character1.append(character1skill)

character2.append("strength")
character2.append(character2strength)
character2.append('skill')
character2.append(character2skill)

print(character1)
print(character2)
```

Comment: dividing `int` by `int` gets you to lose precision. Ex: `11 / 4 = 2`

Comment: @ozgurv not in Python 3, annoyingly.

Answer (score 2):

Note that dividing two integers gets you to lose precision, so don't do that.

```
from random import randrange

def get_random_value():
    return randrange(1, 12, 1) / float(randrange(1, 4, 1))

def calculate_character():
    result = []
    for x in ('strength', 'skill'):
        result.extend([x, get_random_value()])
    return result

character1 = calculate_character()
character2 = calculate_character()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor and extract functions out - according to the functionality (business-logic) of each part:

```
import random

def calc_rand():    
    roll12 = int(random.randrange(1, 12, 1))
    roll4 = int (random.randrange(1, 4, 1))
    return int(roll12 / roll4)

def fill_char(character):   
        character.append("strength")
        character.append(calc_rand())
        character.append('skill')
        character.append(calc_rand())

character1 = []
character2 = []
for character in [character1, character2]:
    fill_char(character)

print (character1)
print (character2)
```